# canonical way to handle default values in a rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tend to write a bunch of this:

```
if params[:my_val]
  my_val=params[:my_val]
else
  my_val=0
end
```

but it seems way too verbose. Most of the ruby specific idioms would still be two lines (like ||=). What is a shorter (and better) way?

thx in advance

Answer (score 2):

one liner

```
my_val =  params[:my_val] || 0
```

Comment: Scrap my answer, this is the one.

Comment: thx - let me take a look at this but this should be about right. Have to test about how empty strings get handled

Answer (score 0):

Not definitely better, but shorter it is:

```
my_val = params[:my_val] ? params[:my_val] : 0
```